# How to loop through yii2 models fetched from the database

Tags: database, activerecord, foreach, yii2, yii2-model

I'm trying to loop through models I fetched from the database and feeding the result to a dataprovider but seems not to work.

```
        $productposted = Product::find()->where(['userId'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->all();

        foreach($productposted as $prod)
        {
            $query =OfferonProduct::find()->where(['productId'=>$prod->id]);
        }
```

The problem seems to be inside the loop; ' $prod->id ' result is an integer. The query returns 'No results found' which isn't true since there are four integers matching the 'productId'.

Comment: You should learn first query builder and gridview / dataprovider for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use yii2 join

```
$query = OfferonProduct::find()
                ->select('offeronProduct.*')
                ->leftJoin('product', '`product`.`id` = `offeronProduct`.`productId`')
                ->where(['product.userId' => Yii::$app->user->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too:

```
$productposted = Product::find()->select('id')->where(['userId'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->asArray()->all();
```

Now you have array of IDs

```
//$productposted = [0 =>[1=>1],1=>[2=>2]....]
```

Next rebuild your query:

```
$result =OfferonProduct::find()->where([
   'IN',  'productId', $productposted
])->all();
```

This way you have one query and your desired result.